# Metafizzy Isotope - Remove inline CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm currently customising Metafizzy's Isotope plugin and I'm trying to remove all inline CSS that is being added.

[image: Screenshot of code]

I know that this code is coming from the js file (https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js) and I've already successfully removed positioning, but I don't know what to remove for the inline style="left:; top:;" and style="height:;" not being appended. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Open webpage with inline css. Open devTools. Right click on node and select copy selector. Chrome Dev Tools will automatically generate selector for that element.

Comment: https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.js should be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all `style` attributes from divs using this code below:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV"),
    len = divs.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++) divs[i].removeAttribute("style");
})
```

If you want to remove only the inline-styles from a specific div class, you can do so by selecting only the divs with the desired class:

```
divs = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item")
```